# "it happens" or "that happens" in context?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Which pronount will be more appropriate to use in the following context?

> If you neglect technique during the squate, it may cost several days weeks off because of a high possibility of injury. **It**/**that** happens pretty often.

I have asked similar question and there is a good answer to that, but I am still confused which pronoun to use in the context. With wich pronoun does the sentence sound more natural and why?

Comment: *Squate* isn't a word, and *it may cost several days weeks off* (as well as the sentence as a whole) is ungrammatical. (I'd guess what you're trying to say is something like: "*If you neglect technique while squatting, there is the possibility of injury that could debilitate you for days or even weeks.*" That aside, either **it** or **that** (or, in this case, I would say you should use **this** instead) would be fine. One is a simple pronoun, the other is a demonstrative pronoun. Which you use is just a matter of choice.

Comment: Tell me please why you used the definite article before the word "possibility" in your example. Would not it be better to "a possibility of injury"?

Comment: You could use *a* instead, if you wished. *The* sounds better to me because it stresses a single, specific thing—the possibility of injury—rather than one of many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

> If you don't use the proper technique there is a high probability of injury and it happens very often.
>
> If you don't use the proper technique there is a high probability of injury and that happens very often.

Neither sentence is very good because probability doesn't "happen".  Injury happens.

It would be better to say:

> If you don't use the proper technique *you can easily injure yourself*.

Now we can choose between **it** and **that** :

> If you don't use the proper technique you can easily injure yourself—and it does happen fairly often.
>
> If you don't use the proper technique you can injure easily yourself—and that does happen fairly often.

Since you're *pointing back* at what you have just said, use **that**.  **That** points at the thing.  **It** is simply a substitute for the thing.  Furthermore, **that** in such a context always points *back* at what has just been said.  **It**, on the other hand, can also anticipate or look forward to its reference. If you use **it**, the listener might think you're about to say something like this:

> If you don't use the proper technique you can easily injure yourself—and it does happen fairly often *that lifters injure themselves doing this lift*.

For these reasons, **that** edges out **it** here on the basis of clarity.

Comment: Does the use of the phrase "cost someone a few weeks" sound strange to your ear? For example: "If you neglect the preoper technique, you will injure yourself and it will cost you a few days off."

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope    While the complement of **cost you** can be almost anything to which value is attached (your reputation,  a lot of money,  your pride, a lot of time, a limb, etc.) the addition of **off** to the phrase **a few days** makes **a few days off** a marginal complement at best.  Please ask this as a separate question. It is interesting in its own right.

Comment: If we  understand it as saying "It will cost you a few days (of) *downtime* [during which you will be unable to make any progress with your lifting]" it isn't too bad.  But that's bending **off** into a new shape.